# Products Problem with 3 variables

Tags: products

Hi need some help with the following Question please

I write down three positive numbers a, b and c.

The product of a and b is 2.
The product of b and c is 24.
The product of c and a is 3.

What is the sum of all three numbers?

Comment: Questions where you don't show your effort tend to be voted down/closed. What exactly did you try? Did you have a problem with some concept, or did your calculations were wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ab=2\implies b=\frac{2}{a}$$
$$bc=24\implies b=\frac{24}{c}$$
$$\frac2a=\frac{24}c\implies c=12a$$
$$ac=a(12a)=12a^2=3\implies a=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$c=12\left(\frac12\right)=6$$
$$b=\frac2{1/2}=4$$
$$\therefore a+b+c=\frac12+4+6=\frac{21}{2}$$

Comment: thank you, i was stuck where b = b.  Post that i've been able to work it through with your help.

Answer (score 0):

You solve the system $ab=2,~bc=24,~ ac=3$ in order to get $a,b,c$. Using the first equation you get for example $a=\frac{2}{b}$ and put into other two equations, and so on. You get $a=\frac{1}{2},~b=4,~c=6$. Then you can compute the sum easily as $10.5$.